# Synchronize Bamboo artifacts

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I have 2 bamboo plans:

1. Build plan has 2 jobs:

   - "compile code", which takes around 2 minutes
   - "generate data" which takes around 10 minutes

Every job generates a different artifact: "exes" and "data" respectively.

2. The second plan has one job, "create installer". It takes both "exes" and "data" shared artifacts and creates an installer.

If I just finished the first plan then I trigger the second, everything works fine. But, what happens if I start the first plan, wait 3 minutes (first artefact "exes" is created), then I start the second plan.

How can I ensure that the installer is created with artifacts from **one plan only**?

Comment: Even if you have 3 minutes gap, it should pickup the latest artifact. If possible, then you can store those artifact in some repository and pick it.

Comment: that's the issue, that it's picking the last artifact from first job and the previous artifact from the last job. Using an external repository is an option, I was hoping I can sync without this.